# Correct types for FunctionComponent HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a HOC like so:

**utils/withGlobalSettings.tsx**

```
interface Props {
  globalSettings: {
    ...
  };
}

export default (Component: React.ComponentType<Props>) => () => {
  const locale = useContext(localeContext);
  const { data } = useQuery(dataGlobalSettingsCollection);
  return <Component globalSettings={globalSettings} />;
};
```

I used this on several simple components and it works great. The problem is when I use it on a component that expects it's own props too, like so:

**components/Products.tsx**

```
interface Props {
  globalSettings: {
    ...
  };
  products: {
    ...
  }[];
}

const Products: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  globalSettings,
  products,
}) => (
  ...
);

export default withGlobalSettings(Products);
```

In this case, typescript complains:

> Property 'products' is missing in type 'PropsWithChildren' but
>   required in type 'Props'.

I believe this is because I haven't set up the HOC correctly to pass through props other than the `globalSettings` one generated inside the prop. How is this achieved with function component HOCs in typescript?

Comment: What is withGlobalSettings? And where is the place where the error throws? - can you add a comment?

Comment: `withGlobalSettings` is the HOC (my first code snippet which I've labelled `utils/withGlobalSettings.tsx`. The error throws on usage of the HOC, specifically on the single parameter `Products`.

Comment: https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb

Comment: @ritaj thanks, I did look at that article already and the examples used are class components, without hooks and with different types.

Comment: The point is that you NEED to use generics there, and return a component with `<Generic & Props>`

Comment: export default should look like `Component: React.ComponentType<Props & (ProductProps |OtherPossibleProps)) >` http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA9JRABSgewAcBnZAbwChlrkAjALmRAFcBbW6CgX1C3iTQAlclRoMmbDlG4Ve0fijxFSlGsjiNiYKKADmAbhkJ8ILcnTIAvMgAU+WgCtGSksgBktjFlwESAHyEASkCrAD5yZC4KCnQbMmQAcjgE+gSAG3w0hIAaOkYARi5AoA

Comment: @Zydnar Doesn't seem to work unfortunately. Could you provide a full example please?

Comment: @ritaj would you be able to provide a full working example? I can't seem to get it working with the information provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
const wrapper = <T extends Props>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) => (ownProps: Omit<T, keyof Props>) => {
  const globalSettings = { test: 2 };
  const props = { globalSettings, ...ownProps };
  return <Component {...props as T} />;
};
```

And you would use it like this:

```
const NewProduct = wrapper(Product);
<NewProduct products={...} />
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require passing some props as the second param on the HOC like: `export default withGlobalSettings(Products, { ...someProps });`?

Comment: yes, wrapped Product component need to get his own parameters from somewhere (since they are mandatory). How where you planning to push those parameters to the product component?

Comment: On usage of the component like so: `<Products products={[...]} />`

Comment: see my edit, now part of the props come from the HOC, and part you provide (similiar how react-redux connect hoc works)

Comment: I wish I could give this more than 1 upvote! Can't tell you how long I've wasted on this today. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad I could help ;)